# In case of an xmlnamespaces, the previous statement must be terminated with a semicolon

Tags: sql-server, xml

I've trying to find a solution that will solve my error, but I couldn't found anything on threads related to this topic and for sure is something I am missing or I am dumb enough to not spot it myself.

I have the following block in MS SQL -

```
DECLARE @XMLFINAL VARCHAR(MAX)
SET @XMLFINAL=''
DECLARE @NUMBER NVARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @XML VARCHAR(MAX)

DECLARE Records CURSOR FAST_FORWARD FOR

SELECT TOP 1 GID FROM PurchasesDocumentsLines

OPEN Records
FETCH NEXT FROM Records INTO @NUMBER
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
BEGIN
SET @XML=''  
SET @XML=(

SELECT  (
WITH XMLNAMESPACES ('uri' as ns1)
SELECT 
ProductCode, OrderedQuantity

FROM PurchasesDocumentsLines WHERE GID=@NUMBER
FOR
XML RAW('EEE'), ELEMENTS
))

FETCH NEXT FROM Records INTO @NUMBER

SET @XMLFINAL=@XMLFINAL+@XML
END

CLOSE Records DEALLOCATE Records
```

I get the below error but I don't really understand what am I missing. I have been trying with semicolon (;) or comma (,) as I can see as a solution on previous colleagues here, but.

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 15
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WITH'.
>   Msg 319, Level 15, State 1, Line 15
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'. If this statement is a common table expression, an xmlnamespaces clause or a change tracking context clause, the previous statement must be terminated with a semicolon.

Any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: Move WITH statement before SELECT ( and add ; before it

Comment: @DmitrijKultasev - you mean here? `SET @XML=''  
SET @XML=

;WITH XMLNAMESPACES ('uri' as ns1)

SELECT  (

SELECT 
ProductCode, OrderedQuantity

FROM PurchasesDocumentsLines WHERE GID=@NUMBER
FOR
XML RAW('EEE'), ELEMENTS
)`

Comment: check my answer

Comment: @DmitrijKultasev - did that and now I get "Incorrect syntax near ';'"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DECLARE @XML VARCHAR(MAX)

;WITH XMLNAMESPACES ('uri' as ns1)
SELECT  @XML=(
SELECT 1 as one
FOR XML RAW('EEE'), ELEMENTS
)
```